# iOS iAds Admob cached data low memory issue

Tags: ios, caching, memory, admob, iad

I have an iOS app that uses iAds and Admob (as a secondary provider when there are no iAds to display).

I have an issue where the app is slowing down/crashing which looks like it is related to low memory on the device.

Initially, I thought it may be a memory leak but I believe I have tracked it down to data being stored in the Cache directory under Documents & Data.  It appears that my app and many others that I use have this problem.  The data in this folder constantly increases in size and can cause problems when the device gets short on memory.  There are 2 folders created in the Caches folder (1 for Admob and another I assume for iAds).

There are a couple of options I was considering to resolve this issue.

1. Delete the cached data when it becomes too large.  This is fairly easy to do but not sure if I am allowed to do this under the terms and conditions of iAds/Admob.
2. Limit the size of the caches folder.  Is this possible?

I have searched on Google, Admob etc but cannot find the answer to the correct way to resolve this issue.  I thought iOS dealt with cases where the memory got too low by automatically clearing out the cache folders but I don't think this is happening.  This is annoying for users as they have no way of removing the cached data without uninstalling their apps.